Weird error: multline* within parbox within align*
I am trying to put a multline* within a parbox within an align.
The purpose is that something like the \testb macro (but with some negative vspace) from the MWE can be used to contain a matrix entry that spans two lines, but the problem is not with the negative vspace or putting it inside the matrix environment, just putting it inside an align environment.
If the outer environment is an equation or multline then there is no problem.
If the inner environment is an align*, like in \testa, then there is no problem.
But the combination of an inner multline* and an outer align (or gather or their starred versions) produces tex's weird error.
It produces the desired output, but eight of the weird error also.
I'm aware that the weird error can be a result of [ following \\ but I don't see where that is happening here.
Note that, per the MWE, the error occurs even without any & and \\ in the outer align environment.
Minimum working example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\providecommand{\testa}[2]{\parbox{#1}{\begin{align*}#2\end{align*}}}
\providecommand{\testb}[2]{\parbox{#1}{\begin{multline*}#2\end{multline*}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\testa{8em}{a &= b \\{} c &= d} % works
\testb{8em}{a  = b \\{} c  = d} % works
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\testa{8em}{a &= b \\{} c &= d} % works
\testb{8em}{a  = b \\{} c  = d} % produces errors
\end{align}

\end{document}

I'd very much appreciate any help.

\providecommand is not the right tool: you do want to define those commands to precisely do that task. If it happens that \testa is defined, you get unpredictable output.

To begin with, you want neither align* nor multline. What you say that “works”, actually doesn't, because you lose the equation number. But it's not all: if I add \fbox around your \parboxes, excess white space is inserted.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\testa}[2]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\begin{align*}#2\end{align*}}}}
\newcommand{\testb}[2]{\fbox{\parbox{#1}{\begin{multline*}#2\end{multline*}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\testa{8em}{a &= b \\ c &= d} % works
\testb{8em}{a  = b \\ c  = d} % works
\end{equation}

\end{document}


What you want is aligned and multlined (needs mathtools). The latter allows to specify a width, the former doesn't, but it's not difficult to add it.
With the optional argument you can set the vertical alignment, see (3) and (4).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{alignedto}{O{c}mb}{%
  % #1 = alignment, #2 = width, #3 = material
  \makebox[#2]{$\begin{aligned}[#1]#3\end{aligned}\mathsurround=0pt$}%
}{}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{multlinedto}{O{c}m}{%
  % #1 = alignment, #2 = width,
  \multlined[#1][#2]
}{\endmultlined}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedto}{8em}a &= b \\ c &= d\end{alignedto}
\begin{multlinedto}{8em}a  = b \\ c  = d\end{multlinedto}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
\begin{alignedto}{8em}a &= b \\ c &= d \\ e &= f\end{alignedto}
\begin{multlinedto}{8em}a  = b \\ c  = d\end{multlinedto}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\begin{alignedto}{8em}a &= b \\ c &= d \\ e &= f\end{alignedto}
\begin{multlinedto}{8em}a  = b \\ c  = d\end{multlinedto}
\end{align}


\begin{align}
\begin{alignedto}[t]{8em}a &= b \\ c &= d \\ e &= f\end{alignedto}
\begin{multlinedto}[t]{8em}a  = b \\ c  = d\end{multlinedto}
\end{align}

\end{document}


